# iPhone not registering with Salesforce Marketing Cloud iOS SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-ios, sdk

I've implemented the iOS Push SDK in my app, and am initialising it, as according to the instructions [here](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/apple.html).

However, the phone doesn't show up in the contacts list, and does not receive push notifications sent from Marketing Cloud.

The SDK status seems to be okay:

```
{
  "MarketingCloud Connection Details" : {
    "Active AccessToken(Masked)" : "d*******************qcrd",
    "Active AppId" : "***"
  },
  "Analytics Details" : {
    "useLegacyPiIdentifier" : false,
    "PiIdentifier" : "",
    "PIAnalyticsEnabled" : false,
    "ETAnalyticsEnabled" : false
  },
  "Push Details" : {
    "Developer has Push Enabled" : "Yes",
    "Device Token" : "****",
    "User has Push Enabled" : "Yes"
  },
  "MarketingCloud SDK Features" : {
    "Enabled by Configuration" : "ETAnalytics, PIAnalytics, Location, Inbox"
  },
  "Privacy Settings" : {
    "Privacy Mode" : "SFMCPrivacyModeNotBlocked"
  },
  "Device Specific Details" : {
    "OS Version" : "12.1.4",
    "Hardware Description" : "iPhone7,1",
    "Device Reported Timezone" : "28800",
    "Device Locale" : "en_SG",
    "DeviceId" : "****",
    "Daylight Savings Time Active" : false,
    "Platform Name" : "iOS"
  }
}
```

The function `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is called correctly, where I set the give the SDK the device token:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    [[MarketingCloudSDK sharedInstance] sfmc_setDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
```

I also noticed this error in the console logs:

> error 14:43:33.290095 +0800   DemoPush    network request failed with
>   status: 401 MarketingCloudSDKControlChannel.m line: 337

So it looks like it's not connecting to Marketing Cloud correctly. 401 seems to imply that it's unauthorised.

I have tried with both the `MarketingCloudSDKConfiguration.json` and using `sfmc_configureWithDictionary` however there's no difference. I'm out of ideas. Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Are you seeing any logs specifying `registration response` (in MarketingCloudSDKFoundation) which may point us to more information? The registration of a device/contact occurs through our registration process (different than the route failing).

Comment: Additionally, please confirm your appId and access token used for configuration match the MobilePush app values in the web account - a mismatch is the only thing I can think of which would result in a 401 from the server.

Comment: Hey sorry looks like I lied, when I switched back to the `MarketingCloudSDKConfiguration.json` file, it started working again. I'm not quite sure why that is. I copied and pasted the values from dictionary into the JSON file and they were exactly the same...